# Beamer and bytefield

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am using **bytefield** package with **beamer** having the same problem  [described here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=latex-beamer-users&max_rows=25&style=nested&viewmonth=200410&viewday=11). According with Till Tantau, in **2004**, *the problem is due to the fact that bytecode redefines the so-called catcode of & to 10.*

Any other hint? Are there alternatives to use?

The code I am using:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \frametitle{}

\begin{bytefield}[leftcurly=.]{32}
\bitheader[endianness=big]{0,22,23,30,31} \\
\begin{leftwordgroup}{}
\bitbox{1}{s} & \bitbox{8}{\textcolor{red}{E}} & \bitbox{23}{f - mantissa}
\end{leftwordgroup} 
\end{bytefield}

}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bytefield` environment does something similar to what `verbatim` does; so a frame containing it should be declared `fragile`:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{What?}

\begin{bytefield}[leftcurly=.]{32}
\bitheader[endianness=big]{0,22,23,30,31} \\
\begin{leftwordgroup}{}
\bitbox{1}{s} & \bitbox{8}{\textcolor{red}{E}} & \bitbox{23}{f - mantissa}
\end{leftwordgroup} 
\end{bytefield}

\end{frame}
```

For "fragile frames" the environment form is mandatory, see section 12.9 of the manual. However, I recommend it also for all other frames, since

```
\frame{...}
```

requires to keep track of the braces, while `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` are more evident in the source file.